# How to simulate trackpad multitouch gestures in Java

Tags: java, mouseevent, awtrobot, trackpad

I’ve been using the `java.awt.Robot` class to control the cursor for actions that are analogous to having a mouse (as in: mouse move, mouse button press, mouse button release). However, on many laptops the trackpad allows more complex gestures that are not possible with a mouse. For example, on a Macbook I can multifinger pinch to show apps, and multifinger swipe to switch desktops. I want to be able to simulate these events in my java app but haven’t found any mention online as to whether it’s possible. Has anyone managed to do this?

Comment: you want to simulate a laptop touchpad with a mouse or what ?

Comment: There’s no external mouse involved. I give my java app permission to take control of the cursor and keyboard on my laptop, but the cursor manipulation methods for AWT's Robot don’t appear to include trackpad-specific gestures.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @user1111929 Nope, I think I never did. We’ll just have to wait a little bit longer...

Comment: I haven't thought about simulating / firing mac gestures before, will look at that, just figured out how to actually use them in a Java app, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535595/what-replaces-gestureutilities-in-java-9, if you take the work further and discover how to generate them please update here