# Multi Touch Gestures in Java / Swing / AWT and Java 17

Tags: java, macos, swing, awt, multi-touch

How can I detect multi touch gestures like pinch / rotate / swipe etc. in a modern Java, like Java 17?

All `com.apple.eawt....` classes have been removed from the JDK.

Answer (score 1):

Posed the same question 4 years ago, and found some hints and clues and got it working, see [What replaces GestureUtilities in Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48535595/what-replaces-gestureutilities-in-java-9)

Comment: Updated the gist linked there to show how to retain cross-platform compilation https://gist.github.com/alanwhite/42502f20390baf879d093691ebb72066