# How to get Apple Java Extensions (com.apple.eawt) work on JDK 7 and higher?

Tags: java, macos, cocoa, java-native-interface

**TL;DR**: Apple has dropped native feature support in Java. Especially touchpad gestures are not working any longer. I wrote a library that does the job using JNI. Take a look at my answer below.

---

I'm searching for about hours to make the Apple Java Extensions work on JDK 7 or 8. I have been trying all I can think of. All threads on the internet about this simply blame the JDK for this. I think this should be solvable, because it worked in JDK 6. For clarity: I can make it work in JDK 6, but I don't want this legacy dependency, because not everybody that will use my application has JDK 6 or knows how to install it, let's say. The goal is to make a double-clickable JAR file that will run as expected with the OS X features (menu bar, gestures, about handler, etc...) with every version of Java installed (greater than JDK 6).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the developer preview release of OS X El Capitan, it became impossible for 99% of average computer users to install Java 6, so this was no longer an option for me. I finally decided to write a native library that will inform Java about gestures through JNI. The project works great and is hosted on GitHub.

Take a look at it here:
https://github.com/mcourteaux/MultiTouch-Gestures-Java

Comment: Agreed. But the lib suggests copying a .so file to /. Some users do not have the permissions to do that. Can your solution be bundled as a jar or it requires manual fiddling with the system for every installation?

Comment: You *could* try to use File.createTempFile instead and in combination with this hack: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15409223/adding-new-paths-for-native-libraries-at-runtime-in-java But this seems not something you want to do. However, I believe that JavaFX has support for multitouch input handling cross-platform.

Answer (score 2):

I just happened to run across your question and noted that it has not been answered yet. I have a Java program that I have been developing on the Mac, and noted that when I ran it under Java 7, the menu bar, Preferences, Quit and About all worked fine using rt. jar in the program's libraries folder and using a MacAppMenuHandler class that I wrote to provide functionality for those items.

However, when I switched to Java 8, they no longer worked. I'm not sure what the issue is though reading other web sites today suggest a "permissions" issue in Java 8 regarding these files.

However, I solved the problem by copying the rt. jar from Java 7 into the program's libraries, and it has continued to work for me while continuing to develop under Java 8.

I suggest this as one possible solution to the problem.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow, this looks amazing news. What version of Java 7 do you have? Which developer? Oracle? Some open source alternative?

Comment: I am running Java 7 and Java 8 standard issue from Oracle, not from an open source or other alternative Java. the rt. jar is: Java 1.7_051

Comment: Did you try if the Touchpad Gestures work with Java 7 as well? It seems that indeed, menu bar works and the Preferences thing as well. But gestures don't. However, I had to use a command line argument to make the menu bar work.

Comment: Oh god.... I always did this: `if (System.getProperty("mjr.version") != null)` and then I did the OS X tweaks. Just removing the condition fixed it... This is an incompatibility with Java 7. Now, only the gestures don't work.

Comment: I'm still not sure why one cannot access the rt. jar OS X components for Java 8 and have everything appear as expected for OS X. I haven't seen any additional discussion about it.

Answer (score 2):

Go on your project Properties and select the Java Build Path Libraries, your JRE System Library should have an Access rules field like the one displayed in the image

[image]

Hit the Edit button and add an access rule to allow access to the com.apple.eawt package.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with "pinch to zoom" - it works in java 6 but not 7 or 8. I came across [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8057788) in the jdk which seems to be responsible.  It says it is fixed in Java 9.